# открытие файлов с базы данных

Tags: c#, winforms

Сделал метод, который получает значения файла с БД , сохраняет и запускает

```
private void OpenFile()
            {
                cs = cs.LoadFile();
                List<FileData> fileDatas = new List<FileData>();
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs.ToString()))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                        int rowindex = postsDataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
                        int selectId = Convert.ToInt32(postsDataGridView.Rows[rowindex].Cells[0].Value);
                        string queryOpen = String.Format("update sta_Messages set \"GetDate\" = CAST(GETDATE() AS BINARY(8)) " +
                                                        "where \"id\" = {0} " +
                                                        "select \"File_Name\", \"File_Ext\", \"File_Content\" " +
                                                        "from sta_Messages where \"id\" = {0}", selectId);
                        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryOpen, conn);
                        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                        while (reader.Read())                                                                                       
                        {
                            string fileName = reader.GetString(0);
                            string fileExt = reader.GetString(1);
                            byte[] fileContent = (byte[])reader.GetValue(2);

                            FileData fileData = new FileData(fileName, fileExt, fileContent);
                            fileDatas.Add(fileData);
                        }
                        if (fileDatas.Count > 0)                                                                                    
                        {
                            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileDatas[0].FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                            {
                                fs.Write(fileDatas[0].FileContent, 0, fileDatas[0].FileContent.Length);

                                Process.Start(fileDatas[0].FileName);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Ошибка! Выберите файл");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Но открывает файл некорректно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вместо текста. Не пойму, проблема в считывании fileContext'a или где. Спасибо за помощь

```
private void UploadFile()
        {
            int selectId = 0;
            string filePath;
            OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                filePath = fileDialog.FileName;
                string fileName = filePath.Substring(filePath.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);                               //Получаем имя файла                
                string fileExtension = filePath.Substring(filePath.LastIndexOf('.') + 1);                           //Получаем расширение файла
                //sendMessageTextBox.Text = fileName;
                byte[] binaryFile;                                                                                  //Массив для хранения бинарных данных файла
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    binaryFile = new byte[fs.Length];
                    fs.Read(binaryFile, 0, binaryFile.Length);
                }

                cs = cs.LoadFile();
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs.ToString()))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                        var table = data.Tables["BTA_USERS"];
                        string row = table.Rows[0]["Пользоватеь"].ToString();
                        string rowValue = usersDataGridView.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
                        if (row == rowValue)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Отправка запрещена!");
                            return;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from BTA_USERS", conn))
                            {
                                cmd.ExecuteReader();
                            }
                        }
                        conn.Close();
                        conn.Open();
                        //Запрос на добавление файла в таблицу
                        int rowindex = usersDataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
                        selectId = Convert.ToInt32(usersDataGridView.Rows[rowindex].Cells[1].Value);
                        string querryUpload = "insert into sta_Messages(\"SetUser_id\", \"GetUser_id\", \"File_Name\", \"File_Ext\", \"File_Content\", \"SetDate\")" +
                                              "values(" + Convert.ToInt32(cs.LastId) + ", '" + selectId + "', '" + fileName + "','" + fileExtension + "','" + binaryFile + "', " + "CAST(GETDATE() AS BINARY(8))" + ")";
                        using (SqlCommand cmdAddMess = new SqlCommand(querryUpload, conn))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                SqlDataReader rezultAddMess = cmdAddMess.ExecuteReader();
                                if (!rezultAddMess.HasRows && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(sendMessageTextBox.Text))               //Проверка на отправку сообщения
                                    MessageBox.Show("Файл отправлено!");
                                else
                                    MessageBox.Show("Ошибка!");
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                            }
                        }
                        GetData();
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Выберите получателя!");
                    }
                }
            }
```

---

```
public ConnectionString LoadFile()
        {
            try
            {
                ConnectionString result;
                XmlSerializer formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ConnectionString));
                using (var fs = new FileStream(GetFileXML(), FileMode.Open))
                {
                    result = (ConnectionString)formatter.Deserialize(fs);
                }
                return result;
            }
            catch
            {
                throw new Exception("Ошибка");
            }
        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы что, считали байты и думаете, что набор байт это строка? Или в чем проблема?

Comment: @tym32167 нужно чтобы файл открывало с исходным текстом, вместо того, что на скрине. Я так понимаю, байты нужно перевести в строку?

Comment: я не знаю, в каком месте вам надо перевести байты в строку, это уже вам решать. Но чтобы это сделать, вам надо знать кодировку файла и у коджировки уже вызывать метод [Encoding.GetString](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getstring?view=netframework-4.8). Или сразу можете читать файл как строку, если вам байты совсем не нужны, для этого есть методы, например `File.ReadAllText(...)`

Comment: Ошибка явно не в приведенном коде. Покажите код, который работает с сохраненным файлом.

Comment: @iluxa1810 добавил код с отправкой файлов, этот вы имели ввиду?

Comment: Ну вот вы выполняете Process.Start(fileDatas[0].FileName); . Какая программа ассоциирована с разрешением вашего файла? Визуально, вы правильно все сохраняете.

Comment: @iluxa1810 дело пахнет ToString() к массиву байт

Comment: @iluxa1810 MS Word, в принципе обычный txt в блокноте также само открывает

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, что когда открывается блокнотом собственноручно, то там написано System.Byte[]?

Comment: @МихаилКошкарёв Да, скорее всего, но на приведенном примере, вроде, все правильно.

Comment: @iluxa1810 ну к примеру отправляю doc или txt файл с каким-то текстом. Потом уже когда пытаюсь считать его с базы файлы открываются с System.Byte[] вместо текста

Comment: @erleug в каком месте кода это происходит? В приведенном куске кода я вижу, что вы считали бинарные данные и записали их в файл.

Comment: Можно увидеть код cs.LoadFile() ? Что-то мне подсказывает, что там собака зарыта.

Comment: @erleug через отладку после получения из БД и до записи в файл как байты поживают?

Comment: @iluxa1810 добавил, но этот метод для загрузки данных строки подключения, я думаю он тут вообще не причем

Comment: @МихаилКошкарёв добавил, что при отладке показывает после получения файла с БД

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Массив байт, который вы получаете из БД:

```
var data = new byte[] { 83, 121, 115, 116, 101, 109, 46, 66, 121, 116, 101, 91, 93 };
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data)); //System.Byte[]
```

А значит, проблема тут (метод `private void UploadFile()`):

```
var variable = new byte[1];//data    
string querryUpload = "blah-blah-blah"+variable;//variable -  массив байт, который тут превращается в строку "System.Byte[]"
```

и в базу вы уже пишите строку "System.Byte[]", которую кастите к массиву байт. Попробуйте передавать данные с помощью параметров.

**UPD**:
Набросал запрос с параметрами, попробуйте использовать его:

```
string querryUpload = "insert into sta_Messages(\"SetUser_id\", \"GetUser_id\", \"File_Name\", \"File_Ext\", \"File_Content\", \"SetDate\") values(@LastID, '@selectedID', '@fileName','@fileExt','@binData', CAST(GETDATE() AS BINARY(8)))";
SqlCommand cmdAddMess = new SqlCommand(querryUpload, conn);
cmdAddMess.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastID", yourId);
cmdAddMess.Parameters.AddWithValue("@selectedID", yourSelectedId);
cmdAddMess.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fileName", fileNameVariable);
cmdAddMess.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fileExt", fileExtensionVariable);
cmdAddMess.Parameters.AddWithValue("@binData", binaryDataVariable);
```

Comment: добавил скрины по последовательности прохождения отладкой в методе `private void UploadFile()` при отправке файла. Изначально байты записываются правильно в переменную `byte[] binaryFile` (1 cкрин), в файлике текст "dsadasdsada", далее при отработке запроса при добавлении `values` переменная также правильно принимает байты (2 скрин), а уже при отработке запроса `SqlCommand cmdAddMess = new SqlCommand(querryUpload, conn)` записывается не текст с файла, а System.Byte[] (3 скрин). Вот не пойму, почему так

Comment: ну Ваш `binaryFile` и не изменится, просто в запрос вместо него подставляется неявное преобразование byte[] -> string (т.е. "System.Byte[]"), и в сам `insert into` попадает строковое значение. Посмотрите в отладчике `cmdAddMess.CommandText`

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы в базу данных записывало в таком формате (загрузил последний скрин). По другому наверно и не получится, а вот `cmdAddMess.CommandText` видно на 3 скрине, туда уже записывается System.Byte[]. Так вот, не врублю, как правильно сохранить файл в БД, так чтобы отображалось все как на последнем скрине, а потом его открыть и был нормальный текст. Я извиняюсь, но уже запутался немного)

Comment: @erleug обновил ответ, возможно в тексте запроса нужно будет подправить экранирование и CAST

Comment: экранирование подправил, заработало. Спасибо за помощь!) Только можно немного растолковать, почему без параметров нормально не записывало

Comment: @erleug потому что при формировании строки запроса произошло преобразования переменной типа byte[] к типу string, из-за оператора "+" - который вызвал метод ToString() объекта